# How changing tabs programatically on LIferay and stop propagation?

Tags: javascript, tabs, liferay, alloy-ui

I would like to change of tab programatically on liferay tabs :

```
<liferay-ui:tabs
    names="one,two" 
    param="tab" 
    refresh="false"
    tabsValues="one,two" 
    type="tabs" value="<%=tabValue %>">

    <liferay-ui:section>
        <%@ include file="/html/one.jsp"%>
    </liferay-ui:section>
    <liferay-ui:section>
        <%@ include file="/html/two.jsp"%>
    </liferay-ui:section>
</liferay-ui:tabs>
```

I would like to avoid that when a user click en o tab, the tab change because I would like to change the tab with a button.

I Know how change tab programatically launching a request to the server and change de active tab. That means that I'm not using javascritp (alloyui) to change between tabs, but I don't know to disable link on tab.

What I would like to do is changing tab programatically via AlloyUI avoiding to launch request to the portlet controller and the most important thing i would like to get is to disable click on the tab.

I have try to no progaging event on tab click by some code like :

```
var nodeListTabs = A.all('.tab');

    nodeListTabs.each(function() {      
        var currentNode = this;     
        currentNode.on('click',function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        });

    });
```

but event click is stil working.

Any idea would be apreciate. Thanks very much

Comment: Do you have static content in your tabs files? If yes, then why don't you try any jQuery specific tab implementation.

Comment: Not, it is dynamic content.

Comment: Try detaching event delegation with tabsNode.detach('click')